# Detect DST flag of future date in C

Tags: c, timezone, dst

I have a system where I am provided with date and time in the form of a string, for example "2011-03-13 03:05:00". I may receive this string at "2011-03-13 01:59:00" and I need to know the length of time between now and the time in the string (6 minutes due to DST change).

I have code that parses the string and creates a `tm` struct which is then converted to a `time_t` with `mktime`. The problem is that I have to set the `tm_isdst` flag manually when I parse the time and so I'm looking for a way to detect whether `tm_isdst` should be set. Any ideas?

I have some ideas for how to deal with the case where there are 2, 2AMs that would be specific to my application, but I still need a way to say "If this time was the current system time, would DST be in effect?"

**Edit:** Idea based on Pete's suggestion. What if I:

1. Check if the time received and current system time have a different hour:
2. If same hour but in the past, add an hour to current time and see if DST flag changed. (If same hour and in future, assume same DST flag as current time (this is most of the year))
3. If different hour, we add 1 hour to current system time and see if DST flag changed

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

According to `man mktime` (on Linux, emphasis mine):

> The  value specified in the tm_isdst
>   field informs mktime() whether or not
>   daylight saving time (DST) is in
>   effect for the time supplied in the tm
>   structure: a positive value means DST
>   is in effect; zero means that DST is
>   not in effect; **and a negative value
>   means that mktime() should (use
>   timezone information and system
>   databases to) attempt to determine
>   whether DST is in effect at the
>   specified time**.

Have you tried that?

(It's "attempt to determine" because some times are fundamentally ambiguous.)

Something you could try for the truly ambiguous times is to see if `mktime` "corrects" your dst flag or not. I'd wager this is non-portable though. Example code, transition set on 31/10/2010, 3am rolls back to 2am in my timezone (Europe/Paris):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printit(int hour, int isdst)
{
    struct tm when;
    memset(&when, 0, sizeof(when));
    when.tm_sec = 0;
    when.tm_min = 30;
    when.tm_hour = hour;
    when.tm_mday = 31;
    when.tm_mon = 9;
    when.tm_year = 110;
    when.tm_isdst = isdst;
    time_t secs = mktime(&when);
    fprintf(stdout, "%2d %ld %d %s", isdst, secs, when.tm_isdst, asctime(&when));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "At %dam\n", i);
        printit(i, 1);
            printit(i, 0);
        printit(i, -1);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
At 1am
 1 1288481400 1 Sun Oct 31 01:30:00 2010
 0 1288485000 1 Sun Oct 31 02:30:00 2010
-1 1288481400 1 Sun Oct 31 01:30:00 2010
At 2am
 1 1288485000 1 Sun Oct 31 02:30:00 2010
 0 1288488600 0 Sun Oct 31 02:30:00 2010
-1 1288488600 0 Sun Oct 31 02:30:00 2010
At 3am
 1 1288488600 0 Sun Oct 31 02:30:00 2010
 0 1288492200 0 Sun Oct 31 03:30:00 2010
-1 1288492200 0 Sun Oct 31 03:30:00 2010
```

As you can see, when the time is non-ambiguous, `mktime` corrects it by setting the right `tm_isdst` and offsetting the time.
When it *is* ambiguous, `tm_isdst` is not changed.

Comment: Thats something I could try, as long as the behavior is deterministic for times like the 2, 2ams problem then I could work around that.

Comment: I don't see a reason why things should not be _deterministic_. As for standardized unfortunately no, mktime can do what it wants for a time during DST transition I think.

Comment: Minor point: Using `time_t secs; printf("%ld", secs);` is a candidate [y2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) bug.  Suggest `time_t secs; printf("%lld", (long long) secs);`  (cast `time_t` to a wide number).

Answer (score 1):

Count on me always for the brute-force way. This might work:

1. completely parse the time string and put it into a tm structure
2. call mktime( ) to get a time_t val on that tm struct
3. add 6 minutes to that new time_t val (using what value for 6 minutes?)
4. call asctime( ) or similar to get a tm struct (i.e., a "broken-down time") from that time_t val
5. in this tm struct you just got back from asctime( ), what does tm_isdst tell you ?

-- Pete

Yes, you are right: the whole mess around time is very badly (even maliciously, one at times believes) designed to trip up programmers and to provide perfect closed-book quiz questions for your whoreson lazy / pedantic / idiotic CS instructors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question as you, I don't know whether this solution can fix it?

```
struct tm *local_tm;
time_t t;
t = time(NULL);
local_tm = localtime(&t);
local_tm->tm_year = 2012-1900;
local_tm->tm_mon = 9 - 1;
local_tm->tm_mday = 13;
time_t utc_time = mktime(local_tm);
```

I think if it you get tm from the system, the tm_isdst field is already set, so the things left is change other fields except tm_isdst, I am not sure whether it is right, but I will try it, if it works for me,I will give further feedback.